# Android horizontalscrollview. Adding views pragmatically

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I am loading some newsitems from a `webservice` I want to add these to a `HorizontalScrollView`.

On iOS I would achieve by looping my news items and then add text labels as subviews to a `ScrollView`. I'am trying to do something similar in android but I can't seem to get it to work properly. No matter what I do, the items are listed below each other.

Heres my code to add the views:

```
public void setupViews(ArrayList<News> news)
{
    HorizontalScrollView scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) getView().findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    for(int i = 0; i < news.size(); i ++)
    {
        News newsItem = news.get(i);
        TextView head = new TextView(this.getActivity());
        head.setText(newsItem.getHead());
        head.setId(100+i);
        layout.addView(head);
    }
}
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView" android:layout_gravity="center"
        >
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

It might be worth noting that I am doing this inside an fragment..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can only add a single child layout to a `ScrollView`

in your case :

- add a `horizontal LinearLayout` (set orientation as horizontal via adding this to your LinearLayout `android:orientation="horizontal"`)
- add stuff inside the `horizontal LinearLayout`

and things will fall right into place, horizontally :-)

Comment: That's exactly what he's doing :)

Comment: He just need to set orientation="horizontal"

Comment: I needed android:orientation="horizontal" for it to work. Silly me, thanks!

Comment: I did - problem was SO would not let me because of the new-question timer thingie..